# Read FB page's feed by app using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to read the page's feed via PHP SDK 4.0 by this request:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, '/626695570712602/feed', 'GET');
```

but i'm getting a `FacebookAuthorizationException` with message `'(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: v2.0GET` and i'm stuck on it.

Also a I have a bit dummy question: do i need any specific access token to read (public) page's feed? Right now i'm only calling the following to retrieve the session:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication("[APP_ID]", "[APP_SECRET]");
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you see the syntax: `$request = new FacebookRequest($session, '/626695570712602/feed', 'GET');`

According to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/3d96359b3b111f7a91b2b52f34fecdcfddfc0171/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php#L147-149 it should be:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/626695570712602/feed');
```

Comment: Official docs on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed, PHP SDK tab (http://oi62.tinypic.com/bgs4fb.jpg)

Comment: You're right, I have switched those two and it works. Thanks! Misleading docs?

Comment: Yea. I tell them to fix it